# SQL Server: cannot alter column which has statistics created by tuning advisor

Tags: sql-server, statistics

When I　execute the SQL statements:

```
alter table Users 
   alter column Name nvarchar(50) null
```

I get this exception

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object '_dta_stat_766625774_22_15' is dependent on column 'Name'.

The root cause is the statistics `_dta_stat_766625774_22_15` was generated by tuning advisor, when alter column it cannot drop it automatically. Anyone have a workaround for this particular issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Just drop that statistics before your run your `ALTER TABLE` statement ....

Comment: To drop statistics is okay, but It's not the best way to resolve my issue, much appreciated.

Comment: if dropping the statistics is not the best way, then which way is the best? Which alternatives do you know?

Comment: I don't know yet. I had dropped it and used Tuning Advisor to rebuild it again. thanks all of you guys.